# how to set in laravel blade the display of a tag p depending on whether the data passed has a value or is empty or null

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

As already described, I want to display the input in my show depending on whether the data present in the view has a value (so it is shown to me through a p tag) or do not show this p tag if the present data is null or empty.

If it is empty or null do not show anything

This is my code:

```
<div>
    <h4>Code</h4>
    <p>{{$client->code}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the simplest way would be to wrap it in an [if statement](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#if-statements):

```
<div>
    <h4>Code</h4>
    @if(!empty($client->code))
        <p>{{ $client->code }}</p>
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: Barring any issues with `$client->code`'s "truthyness", this is the correct approach. Could use `@if(!empty($cient->code)) ... @endif`, or `@unless($client->code === null) ... @endunless`, etc, but same idea 

Comment: I think isset will fix the trust worthiness

Comment: @jeremykenedy `isset()` would return true for an empty string so I think `!empty(...)` is more appropriate in this case. 